# Preg_replace not deleting text in between found tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, preg-replace

I'm trying to use preg_replace to delete all titles from within a string. Its part of a wordpress excerpt function, taking out all `<h3>Title</h3>` tags within the body of a post, since they break up the flow of paragraphs otherwise.

So the aim is that in a string such as

`"<p>Here is some info.</p><h2>A new section</h2><p>Here is some more info.</p>"`

My output string would be

`"<p>Here is some info.</p><p>Here is some more info.</p>"`

I'm pretty certain my regex is the correct one. But preg_replace doesn't appear to be deleting header tags.

```php
    $regex = array (
            '\<h1[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h1\>',
            '\<h2[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h2\>',
            '\<h3[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h3\>',
            '\<h4[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h4\>',
            '\<h5[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h5\>',
            '\<h6[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h6\>'
            );

    preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
```

The text within tags is staying firmly in place, ie.

`"<p>Here is some info.</p><h2>A new section</h2><p>Here is some more info.</p>"`

*Edit: Didn't realise my query was lacking delimiters. Similar to other questions, but wouldn't have found them through googling "delimiter" error, as wasn't receiving the error. Didn't have Php Error Reporting turned on the site due to not having access to ftp at the time. Was having to simply edit through wordpress theme editor. Conceivable that others could have same issue, this question might be a relevant reference for them in future.*

Comment: Maybe `preg_replace($regex, '$1', $text);` ?

Comment: Nope that didn't work either. I'm pretty sure my whole preg_replace is failing for some reason actually. When I set it to ```$text = preg_replace ($regex, '', $text); ``` I get nothing at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you get any warning for your example code?
The following is working as expected

```
$text = "<p>Here is some info.</p><h2>A new section</h2><p>Here is some more info.</p>";
$regex = array (
    '#\<h1[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h1\>#',
    '#\<h2[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h2\>#',
    '#\<h3[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h3\>#',
    '#\<h4[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h4\>#',
    '#\<h5[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h5\>#',
    '#\<h6[^]]*\>(.*?)\</h6\>#'
);

$replaced = preg_replace($regex, '', $text);

echo $text;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo $replaced;
```

EDIT

Check if you you have php warning disabled

Comment: The warnings came from not having a regex delimiter, which are the hashmarks in your answer (just for clarification)